# Background on the functional equation $F(x+1)+F(x)=f(x)‎$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations, functional-calculus, tag-removed

In the theory of indefinite sums, anti-differences and finite calculus,  ‎the following ‎difference ‎functional ‎equation ‎and ‎its ‎solutions ‎are ‎very ‎important:

‎$$‎\bigtriangleup ‎F(x):=F(x+1)-F(x)=f(x) ‎\quad‎\quad‎(1),‎$$

where‎ ‎$‎\bigtriangleup‎$ ‎is ‎the ‎forward ‎difference ‎operator when $f$ is given and $F$ is unknown. ‎ Also‎, if ‎$‎‎D_f=\mathbb{R}$‎, then there exists a special solution ‎$‎‎F_0(x)$ for equation (1) and ‎ ‎we ‎have ‎the ‎general ‎solutions of ‎it ‎as ‎follows‎: ‎‎‎$‎‎F=F_0+‎\lambda$,‎‎ ‎which ‎‎$‎‎‎\lambda$ ‎is a‎ ‎one-periodic ‎function.‎

Now‎, in my research I deal to the following functional equation
‎
$$F(x+1)+F(x)=f(x)‎‎$$

‎but I don't have any knowledge about it and its solution. ‎ What is the name of this equation and where can I learn more about it?

Answer (score 5):

Denote $g(x)=F(x) (-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ and get the difference equation for $g$. Multiplying by $\sin \pi x$ also works.

Comment: Do you mean that by applying this $g$, the new functional equation turns into the functional equation (1)?

Comment: Or you give just an special solution.

Comment: Yes, it turns out into (1)

Comment: ‎‎‎@Fedor Petrov: ‎‎‎Thanks for your answer firstly, but I checked it again and found that this ‎$‎‎g$ ‎doesn't ‎work ‎when ‎‎$\lfloor x\rfloor$‎ ‎is ‎even.

Comment: Henec, if ‎we denote ‎‎$h(x)=F(x)‎\varepsilon(x)‎ (-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor} ‎\quad‎\text{where}‎\quad‎ \varepsilon(x) = \begin{cases} 
        1 & \text{if } \lfloor x\rfloor\text{is odd}, \\ 
        -1 & \text{if }\lfloor x\rfloor \text{is even}. 
        \end{cases} $‎‎‎‎
        then ‎$‎‎h$ ‎works ‎for ‎all ‎‎$‎‎x$.‎
     
‎

Comment: Now, ‎could ‎you ‎explain ‎that ‎how ‎you ‎obtain ‎your ‎answer ‎or ‎introduce ‎me ‎some related  ‎books ‎or ‎referenc‎es to do that.

Comment: Your $h$ equals $F$, remove one of multiples (any of two).